# Javascript Regex Form validation returning error

Tags: javascript, php, regex, forms, validation

I have been trying to validate my form email input with these line of codes.

```js
function validate() {
  var emailFirst = document.getElementById('email1');
  var emailFirstRGex = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  var emailFirstTest = emailFirstRGex.test(emailFirst);

  if (emailFirstTest === false) {

  alert('hello20');
}
   }
```

My form

```html
<form class="needs-validation" novalidate method="POST" action="nomination2.php" onsubmit="validate()">
```

I keep getting the hello20 response. Meanwhile i have tried this regex against emails on the console without error. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

`emailFirstTest` is declared inside your function, so checking for it outside the function means it is out of scope and doesn't exist.

Just define it above your function:

```
var emailFirstTest  = '';

function validate() {
  emailFirst = document.getElementById('email1');
  var emailFirstRGex = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  var emailFirstTest = emailFirstRGex.test(emailFirst);
}
```

Comment: I did not declare it outside the function, i posted the question wrongly and I have corrected it.

Comment: console log the emailFirst  var

Comment: I got the correct email I entered, when I console.log, it is just not passing the test

Comment: `emailFirstRGex` is a string. Where is this `.test()` function coming from?

Comment: Try `var regex = new RegExp(emailFirstRGex ); var emailFirstTest = regex.test(emailFirst);` If it works I'll update my answer

Comment: test returns a boolean true or false

Comment: try putting your regex string into a RegExp object like i commented above